# Which method is better for sending a stream of images between two processes, local TCP/IP connection or Interprocess communication?

Tags: tcp, stream, interprocess

Assuming that I have to copy each image on the stream (I cannnot simply access that data with any mutex protection, it must be copied anyway), which method is better, pros/cons?

I would like to know also how much performance loss this implied compared to using the images in the same process.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For images, IPC through [shared memory](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) would be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

At least Windows' firewalls can interfere even with local TCP/IP connections. Therefore I would prefer shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

In term of performance, IPC through shared memory is the best option but IMHO, 
even if sockets consume a little more processing, they will give you a better result in term of evolutivity of your software.

Comment: what is ftw? (I can imagine F*ck The Word, but I'm not native english...)

Answer (score 1):

Google "Memory Mapped Files"

Comment: I'm reading about it, but I can't figure out how well does the I/O of a memory mapped file perform, compared to IPC.

Comment: Memory-mapped IO *is* a form of IPC.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the VCAM example of a DirectShow capture device (available at:
http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads/vcam.zip)

This driver appears to the O/S as a video capture device and would run in the destination process. The source would use shared memory buffers to feed it frames to inject.

While more complicated than a minimal shared-memory IPC scheme, it gives an incredible advantage in that your video pipes can connect to most media player programs, capture and editing tools, etc.

I have done this several times, including features like sinks, mixers, Freeframe effect plugins, and so on. It should take a day or two to hack together.

Comment: Do you know any multiplatform solution similar to this? Thanks!